# D3 IE8 Compatibility?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, d3.js, visualization

Is there any way to make D3 compatible with IE8?
Many of the posts here and in the documentation suggested using aight.
https://github.com/shawnbot/aight/blob/master/aight.js

However, I added the lines/file mentioned to my html, but this still doesn't work in ie8.
http://matthewpiatetsky.com/jsdemo.html

Does anyone know if there are any additional steps I need to take?

Perhaps use r2d3? Not sure how to do that, but will try to figure out

Answer (score 12):

D3 uses SVGs to graph and since IE8 does not support SVG it won't work.I would give R2D3 a try, it shims SVG via Raphael to be compatible with D3. There are some limitations as some functionality won't be available. Look at https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/ for more details

Comment: yeah that's what I figured was the problem. I'm not sure how r2d3 fixes it though because right now if i just put in the required lines/files for r2d3 it still doesn't work for ie8 as you can see  http://matthewpiatetsky.com/jsdemo.html

Comment: i see now it looks like i can't just include the js file, but need to use the makefile? will try to figure that out

Comment: yeah i think i have the full file now but i don't think it works

Comment: d3 doesn't "use" SVG, it's just the recommended graphic system. You can definitely use d3 without SVG and simple DOM elements, and still get pretty far with it.

Answer (score 7):

aight.js worked for me, just need to take care importing it before d3.js

Answer (score 3):

Many good [demos of R2D3](http://webmonarch.github.io/d34raphael/), and [Aight demos](http://vallandingham.me/d3_without_svg.html) now exist.

I think that re-coding your question to demo it in one of these libraries is out-of-scope of SE, but hope you find the links useful.